# AngularJS Check value in ng-repeat array object

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I will check date with due date in data. If any `due date <= date` exists it is display true in html, If any `due date <= date` don't exists it is display false in html  (show only 1 value). My data and my javascipt:

```
$scope.data = {
  project: [
    {
      id: 1,
      dueDate: '2021-10-30 00:00:00.000000',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      dueDate: '2021-10-10 00:00:00.000000',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      dueDate: '2021-10-20 00:00:00.000000',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      dueDate: '2021-10-5 00:00:00.000000',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      dueDate: '2021-10-2 00:00:00.000000',
    },
  ]
};

// Format date
$scope.date = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
$scope.convertToDate = function(stringDate) {
  var dateOut = new Date(stringDate);
  return dateOut;
};
// Format Due Date
$scope.getDueDate = function(dateTime) {
  return new Date(dateTime).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
};
```

My html:

```
<div ng-repeat="prj in data.project">
    <div ng-if="date <= getDueDate(prj.dueDate)">
        true
    </div>
    <div ng-if="date > getDueDate(prj.dueDate)">
         false
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display with the above data is one value `true`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the wording of what you're asking for or what the problem is. Your code works fine in [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-xx9oll?file=home/home.controller.js), accurately showing true or false for each project.